# Cannot AutoLayout two UILabels side by side in Tablecell with dynamic widths

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I have a custom cell that needs to layout two UILabels side by side. The width of both Labels is dynamic and could wrap.

The AutoLayout I have defined fails under following circumstances

1. Scroll the Cell and its containing Section so that it is all on screen.
2. Rotate device into Landscape (needs to be a big enough View so that the Cell is of screen)
3. Rotate back and the left label will be compressed.

If the whole of the Cell and containing Section are not on Screen prior to rotation the layout does not fail

Here are a couple of screenshots of it working and after a rotation

[image]

[image]

This is the layout with the following constraints

```
this.ContentView.AddConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
        this.TextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left,
        1.0f, (nfloat)LeftRightPadding));

this.ContentView.AddConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
        this.TextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        1.0f, (nfloat)TopAndBottomPadding));

this.ContentView.AddConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
        this.TextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        1.0f, 0 - (nfloat)TopAndBottomPadding));

this.ContentView.AddConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
        this.DetailTextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Right,
        1.0f, 0 - (nfloat)LeftRightPadding));

this.ContentView.AddConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
        this.DetailTextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        1.0f, (nfloat)TopAndBottomPadding));

this.ContentView.AddConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
        this.DetailTextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        1.0f, 0 - (nfloat)TopAndBottomPadding));

this.ContentView.AddConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
    this.DetailTextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.TextLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Right,
        1.0f,
        10));
```

How do stop that squeezing of the left hand side label?

Comment: Increase left compression resistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the content hugging priority of UILabels above 750.

Initially the content hugging and content compression resistance priorities will be like below.

[image]

Set the values as follows

[image]

Any values can be set to these, but according to your priorities.

Comment: I suppose you mean the `Content Compression Resistance Priority` as in the image?

Comment: I did try Compression Resistance before. I will try hugging and Resistance now

Comment: You say "above 750" but have them set at 750 in the image. Is 750 enough?

Comment: Neither Hugging nor Compression work. I do have an update to the onscreen\offscreen situation and will update the question

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee - Sorry, putting the image was a bit misleading. I put the image just to show the fields in IB. You may increase the content hugging priority above the compression resistance priority. Have you tried setting the content hugging priority to 751(or above) and content compression resistance priority to 250.

Comment: On both Labels or just the Left one?

Comment: I have set Compression to 250 and Hugging to 751 on left most Label and that has fixed it

Comment: Yes. If you can remove the Image (unclear) and update your answer to what you said in the earlier comment "ave you tried setting the content hugging priority to 751(or above) and content compression resistance priority to 250" I'll accept your answer

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee - If the answer is correct, please accept it.